# failed to run flutter project after reinstalling windows

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

i've been working on a project, and then reinstalled windows while my project was on a seperate disk so it was untouched, when i installed the flutter environment (a new project would work fine), i still got issues running my older project, even though it runs on web with no problems i got this when trying running it on an emulator or a real device with flutter run -v :

```
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 39s
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
[        ] You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 202 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 197 up-to-date
[        ] Watched directory hierarchies: [D:\Projects\DzApp\android]
[ +639 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 40.9s)
[   +2 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 43,128ms.
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:760:9)
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1297:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:339:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:285:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:115:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +158 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 152ms
[        ] Running 1 shutdown hook
[   +5 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

./gradlew -v

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-07-14 12:48:15 UTC
Revision:     c7db7b958189ad2b0c1472b6fe663e6d654a5103

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.9 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.9+11-LTS-201)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

flutter doctor :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3930], locale en-GB)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.86.0)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

I tired upgrading flutter, downgrading flutter, upgrading the gradle, downgrading the gradle, flutter clean ... flutter pub repair cache, running on android studion, running the android folder on android studio, invalidate cache ... everything i found on the internet and still not running on neither emulator nor a real device.

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, it says to try running the build with ` '--warning-mode all'`, did that provide any extra information?

Answer (score 0):

try this to return the gradle version for the previous version
:

```
go to android>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties
```

in this file go to attribute named :distributionUrl
annd change the version for gradle into 7.5 or 8 then run the app  but it take some times for install the gradle file from internet

Comment: I tried this, but no luck